# WPF Printing prints on 1 system and not on other

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a **WPF application** in which I have 3 forms of prints. In 2 ways, I use directly a window's visual and use `PrintVisual(myPanel, "Title")` to print it. And in 3rd, I got to print multiple pages so I am using `FlowDocument`, `StackPanel` and finally `IDocumentPaginatorSource` and call `PrintDocument` to print.

All the code is working perfectly on my system. I can perform Print on `OneNote` and `XPS` and it works as expected. But the same app, when I try to run on other system it shows blank page for all 3 prints. `PrintVisual` is supported on `.NET 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5`, so I can't find a reason for it not to work.

I will also share my some code, for better clarity :

```
    // 1 PRINT 
    public void PrintRegister()
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
            pd.PrintVisual(this, "Register Window");

        return;
    }

    // 2 PRINT  
    public static void PrintAttendanceOf(System.Data.DataRow r1) {
        PrintLayoutWindowPORT plw = PrintUtility.CreatePrintLayoutWindowPORTObject(r1); // PORTRAIT

        Canvas p1 = PrintUtility.CloneCanvas(plw._PrintCanvas, 5);
        Grid myPanel = new Grid();
        myPanel.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        myPanel.Children.Add(p1);

        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PageRangeSelection = PageRangeSelection.AllPages;
        PrintQueue pq = pd.PrintQueue;
        pq.DefaultPrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
        pd.PrintTicket = pq.DefaultPrintTicket;

        double pageWidth = pd.PrintableAreaWidth;
        double pageHeight = pd.PrintableAreaHeight;

        myPanel.Measure(new Size(pageWidth, pageHeight));
        //myPanel.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(1, 1), myPanel.DesiredSize));
        myPanel.UpdateLayout();

        if (pd.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false))
        {
            pd.PrintVisual(myPanel, "Attendance Chart");
        }

        pd = null;
        plw.Close();
        plw = null;
        myPanel = null;
        p1 = null;

        return;
    }
```

Code for the 3rd Print i.e. Multiple Pages is quiet long, hence have not added it now here. If required, can post it.

Can anyone help me know the reason for printing blank page and no contents on other system. I feel some sort of compatibility or system or resource may be required or what else?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks